# Are their any known and mysterious Vedic/Post-Vedic scriptures which aren't available to the public?

Tags: scripture, mysterious

I am wondering if their are any mysterious, known of existing, but not available in full for the public and what these scriptures consist of. I am looking for scriptures which have secret or esoteric knowledge not for the public and mentioned by commentators, but not known today.

Comment: Can you elaborate and explain your question?